# Template Specialization over derived class

Tags: c++, templates

I don't know if it is possible, I checked on StackOverflow, I found a lot of stuff but nothing that really fit my problem (or I don't see the relation).
What I'd like to do is something like that:

```
class Bean
{
    public:
    Bean(){}
virtual ~Bean(){}
    template <class T>
    bool set_(T){return false;}
    template <class T>
    bool get_(T&){return false;}
};
template <class T>
class GenericBean: public Bean
{
    protected:
    T type;
};
class Prova :  public GenericBean<int>
{
    public:
      Prova(){type = 0;}

   template<int> bool set_(int value){ type=value;}
   template<int> bool get_(int& value){value = type;}

};
```

I'd like to have on object like Prova, cast to Bean and get the specialized function,
What I want to do is something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Bean.h"

using namespace std;
class VirtualMessage
{
public:
    VirtualMessage(void){}
    virtual ~VirtualMessage(void){} 

    template <class ReturnValue, class Item>
    bool Get(ReturnValue & val)
    {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < m_vData.size(); i++)
            {
                if(m_vData[i].get_<ReturnValue>(val))
                  return true;
            }
    }
    template <class Item, class Value>
    bool Set(Value val)
    {
         Item bean;
         if(bean.set_<Value>(val))
         {
           m_vData.push_back(bean);
           return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
protected:
     vector<Bean> m_vData;
};
```

Main:

```
#include "VirtualMessage.h"
#include "Bean.h"
int main()
{
    VirtualMessage msg;
    if(msg.Set<Prova ,int>(4))
        printf("Test 1 passed");
}
```

this code doesn't compile

Maybe nobody will use it, but I wrote something that fits my need. It's not perfect, I have to work on it but is a begin:

```
#define UNIQUE(T)   unsigned int GetID(){return UniqueType<T>::id();}

struct UniqueTypeBase 
{ 
   static unsigned int _ids; 
}; 

unsigned int UniqueTypeBase::_ids = 0; 
template <class T> 
struct UniqueType : public UniqueTypeBase 
{ 
   static const unsigned int id() 
   { 
      static unsigned int typeId = 0; 
      if (typeId == 0) 
         typeId = ++_ids; 
      return typeId; 
    } 
 }; 


template <class T>
class TemplateBean
{
  public:
     T m_tValue;
     template<class T> set_(T){return false;}
     template<class T> get_(T&){return false;}

     bool set_(T value){    m_tValue    =   value;      return true;}
     bool get_(T& value)    {   value       =   m_tValue;return true;}
};

class Prova :  public TemplateBean<int>
{
public:
    UNIQUE(Prova)
    Prova(){m_tValue = 0;}
};
class Prova2 :  public TemplateBean<float>
{
   public:
     UNIQUE(Prova2)
     Prova2(){m_tValue = 0;}
};


class VirtualMessage
{
  public:
    VirtualMessage(void){}
    virtual ~VirtualMessage(void){} 
    template <class Item, class ReturnValue>
      bool Get(ReturnValue & val)
    {
         Item a;
         map<unsigned int, void*>::iterator it;
         it = m_TagMap.find(a.GetID());
         if(it != m_TagMap.end())
         {
             Item*  pItem = reinterpret_cast<Item*>(it->second);
             if(pItem->get_(val))
                return true;
          }
          return false;
     }
    template <class Item, class Value>
     bool Set(Value val)
    {
      Item* pBean = new Item();
      if(pBean->set_(val))
      {
           m_TagMap[pBean->GetID()] = (void*)pBean;     
           return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  protected:
    map<unsigned int, void*> m_TagMap;
 };
```

Test Main:

```
 int main()
 {
    VirtualMessage msg;
    if(msg.Set<Prova ,int>(4))
        printf("Test 1 passed\n");
    if(!msg.Set<Prova,float>(4.00))
        printf("Test 2 succed\n");
    if(msg.Set<Prova2,float>(4.00))
        printf("Test 3 succed\n");
    int a=0;
    if(msg.Get<Prova>(a))
         printf("%d = 4...if 4=4 test passed\n",a);
     float b=0;
    if(msg.Get<Prova2>(b))
        printf("%f = 4...if 4=4 test passed\n",b);
    getchar();
  }
```

Comment: Remark: using `protected` attributes makes maintaining invariants impossible and thus debugging harder.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood the use of templates.

Templates are *blueprints* to build classes or methods, that the compiler use to produce real classes and methods (which is called instantiation).

As such, they are purely a compile-time facility. Therefore, they cannot be `virtual`, and thus *overloading* a template method in a derived class does not mean what you expect. It *hides* the base class method when used from derived (statically) but you still call the base class method if you use a reference or pointer to the base class.

What you are trying to achieve is, unfortunately, impossible with templates: it requires a runtime check.

Furthermore, you are using a `std::vector<Bean>` which will not work as intended. Polymorphic types shall not be manipulated by values in C++, you need a `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Bean> >` or `boost::ptr_vector<Bean>`...

I would recommend reading a good C++ primer before attempting the kind of task you have set yourself upon. You need a basic introduction to C++ paradigms... and gotchas. And there are a lot of gotchas.

Comment: Well I want a help to do something like that. Your comment didnt' help me, I resolve by myself without introduction to C++

Comment: @perusopersonale: you should definitely read a (good) introduction to C++ (follow the white rabbit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), incidentally, you are reinventing (somewhat) Introspection and Reflection in C++. You may wish to read on the Visitor pattern, for example. And you might `Boost.Any` helpful... (it is MUCH nicer than `void*`, and notably... type safe)